# "saved_changes" like method for gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I need to know is there any method already available for gorm like we have for active_record like `saved_changes` that can be accessed in model level hooks/callbacks?

If not, is there any best way to it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this method in `BeforeSave` hooks - https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Check-Field-has-changed